# Text extraction from PDF with search criteria

Tags: r, pdf

I need to extract text from a PDF, I have a list of keywords which tell me what text part I need to extract.

PDF looks something like this:

- **Schema element:** Keyword1 *This is my keyword*
- **Fontsize:** 14 *I dont need this*
- **Guide to complete schema element:** *Text text. This is the text I need and it can between 2 and 3 lines long. And even contain multiple sentences.*
- **Schema element:** Keyword2 *This is my keyword*
- **Fontsize:** 18 *I dont need this*
- **Guide to complete schema element:** *Text text, this is the text I need and it can between 2 and 3 lines long. And even contain multiple sentences. This text is different from the text above.*

This is my code so far:

```
library(pdftools)
library(pdfsearch)
library(tidyverse)
pdf <- pdf_text(dir(pattern = "*.pdf")) %>%
read_lines()
Keyword_list <- c("swDisproportionateCost", `"swDisproportionateCostOtherEULegislation", "swExemptionsTransboundary","swDisproportionateCostAlternativeFinancing","swDisproportionateCostAnalysis","swDisproportionateCostScale")`
```

Then I tried using keyword_search but it only told me which line the keyword was in.

I would like to extract the text in *cursive* into a new column in my keyword_list. I think it can be done with regex using the keyword and the text in **bold** as start and stops.

Here is a link to the pdf.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kyyzr5wnh8z87if/FINAL%20Draft4_WFD_Reporting_Guidance_2022_resource_page.pdf?dl=0

Comment: where do you get the function pdf_text()?

Comment: Hi Rafn. This would certainly be possible, but we need to see the actual pdf. Is there a way you can add a link to it via dropbox or similar? Otherwise, this is like trying to shoot at a target blindfolded with someone just _describing_ where the bullseye is.

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron The text i search for is the word after Schema element and the text i need to extract is text after Guidance on completion of schema element in the corrosponding box in the PDF. I added some information in the post.

Comment: @Rafn thanks for posting the link. It would not have been possible to get the answer without this.

Comment: pdfminer.six is a great package for this in Python. @Rafn Is it an option for you to use Python with reticulate?

Comment: We do have Python as a tool to work with, though i have never used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a rather pedestrian text extraction job. There are many ways to do it, and I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do it than this, but this one does the job:

```r
library(pdftools)
library(dplyr)

keywords <- pdf_text("mypdf.pdf") %>%
strsplit("Schema element:") %>%
  lapply(function(x) x[-1]) %>%
  lapply(function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, "\r\n"), `[`, 1)) %>%
  unlist %>%
  trimws()

text <- pdf_text("mypdf.pdf") %>%
  strsplit("Guidance on completion of schema element:") %>%
  lapply(function(x) x[-1]) %>%
  lapply(function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), `[`, 1)) %>%
  lapply(function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, "\r\n"), 
                            function(y) paste(y[-length(y)], collapse = ""))) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  {gsub("  ", " ", .)} %>%
  trimws() %>%
  strsplit("Guidance on contents") %>%
  sapply(`[`, 1)

df <- tibble(keywords, text)
```

So the result looks like this:

```
df
#> # A tibble: 15 x 2
#>    keywords                       text                                                   
#>    <chr>                          <chr>                                                  
#>  1 swExemption44Driver            "Required. Select from the enumeration list the driver~
#>  2 swExemption45Impact            "Required. Select from the enumeration list the impact~
#>  3 swExemption45Driver            "Required. Select from the enumeration list the driver~
#>  4 swDisproportionateCost         "Required. Indicate if disproportionate costs have bee~
#>  5 swDisproportionateCostScale    "Conditional. Select from the enumeration list the  sc~
#>  6 swDisproportionateCostAnalysis "Conditional. Select from the enumeration list the  an~
#>  7 swDisproportionateCostAlterna~ "Conditional. Select from the enumeration list the  al~
#>  8 swDisproportionateCostOtherEU~ "Conditional. Indicate whether the costs of basic  mea~
#>  9 swTechnicalInfeasibility       "Required. Report how ‘technical infeasibility’ has be~
#> 10 swNaturalConditions            "Required. Select from the enumeration list the  eleme~
#> 11 swExemption46                  "Required. Select from the enumeration list the reason~
#> 12 swExemption47                  "Required. Select from the enumeration list the  modif~
#> 13 swExemptionsTransboundary      "Required. Indicate whether the application of  exempt~
#> 14 swExemptionsReference          "Required. Provide references or hyperlinks to the  re~
#> 15 driversSWExemptionsReference   "Required. Provide references or hyperlinks to the  re~
```

Comment: Hi @Allan Cameron 

I am getting an error:  Error in strsplit(x, "\r\n") : non-character argument.

I added a new link to the full PDF, i thought it was confidential but apparantly it's not.
Your code worked on the 4 pages i sent you first, but it doesn't work on the full PDF.

Comment: @Rahl I wouldn't expect it to work on a different pdf. Text parsing requires knowledge of the exact document you are trying to parse, which is why I asked you to include a link to the pdf you wanted parsed. Effectively, I have wasted my time parsing a document you didn't need parsed!

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake thinking i was working with a confidential report. It was my understanding that these scripts could be translated to work on similar jobs, but i will try and rework your code so it fits. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Hi @Allan Cameron could you by any chance help me with a expansion of this problem in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650928/how-do-i-extract-text-from-pdf-and-add-to-df-in-r?